# RegEx to find any uppercase word followed by a colon

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I need a RegEx to match an uppercase string ending with a colon. The string can contain spaces, numbers and periods.  So that if:

```
mystring = "I have a C. GRAY CAT2:"
```

I want the coldfusion expression

```
REFind("[A-Z0-9. ][:]",mystring)
```

to return the number 9, matching "C. GRAY CAT2:". Instead, it is returning the number 21, matching only the colon. I hope that a correction of the regex will solve the problem. Of course I have tried many, many things.
Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps `[A-Z][A-Z0-9. ]*:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using

```
[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9. ]*:
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y5q2zb/1)

**Details**

- `[A-Z0-9]` - an uppercase letter or digit (in case the first char can be a digit, else remove `0-9`)
- `[A-Z0-9. ]*` - zero or more uppercase letters/digits, `.` or space
- `:` - a colon.

**Variations**

To avoid matching `345:` like substrings but still allow `23 VAL:` like ones, use

```
\b(?=[0-9. ]*[A-Z])[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9. ]*:
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y5q2zb/2). Here, `\b(?=[0-9. ]*[A-Z])` matches a word boundary first, and then the positive lookahead `(?=[0-9. ]*[A-Z])` makes sure there is an uppercase letter after 0+ digits, spaces or dots.

If you do not expect numbers at the start of the sequence, i.e. out of `I have a 22 C. GRAY CAT2:`, you need to extract `C. GRAY CAT2`, use [Sebastian's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46449410/regex-to-find-any-uppercase-word-followed-by-a-colon/46449441#comment79854500_46449410) ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/iyUmch/1)).

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor.  Sebastian's suggestion also extracted the "I" at the beginning of the string, which is not what I needed, since the matching string would have contained the lower-case letters "have a".

Comment: Oops, there was some string at the beginning of the answer I did not finish. Removed to avoid confusion.

Comment: Wiktor (at):  I am still using your original suggestion, but have run into the problem that my sources occasionally use characters from 128-255, so that MÜNCHEN: appears in my sources as MÃœNCHEN: so that the RegEx matches NCHEN:
Can the RegEx be adapted to treat such special characters as if they were uppercase letters, so that they match entire strings containing "special characters"?

Comment: @Commata That would be a work around and it won't necessarily work in 100% cases. The solution is to read the texts from sources with the correct encoding (looks like its source encoding is WINDOWS-1251 but it is displayed as WINDOWS-1252).

Comment: (at)Wiktor I shall try a pass over the source code with ReplaceList first, that should do the trick. Most of the umlauts in the source code are OK, but for some reason a few are escaped. You write that the source encoding is displayed as WINDOWS-1252, but did I name the source? :-) And why can you write at-signCommata to me but when I write at-signWiktor to you it does not appear in the comment online? Could it be because I am using a German keyboard to type my at-sign?

Comment: @Commata That was a shot in the dark, I just pasted the word you shared into the input field at https://2cyr.com/decode/ and checked what encoding yields a correct word. Your `@Wiktor` in your comments *under my answer* is redundant as I receive notifications by default. If I do not add `@` and your username, you won't receive a notification of my comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155490/discussion-between-commata-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 0):

Have revised the selected answer to my own question to cover the German special characters.

```
[A-Z][A-Z0-9.ÜÄÖß ]*:
```

This appears to work, however the Germans have recently added a capital ß to their alphabet, which is surely not on most keyboards yet, and therefore will not be a problem for the RegEx for a while.